# PHP: How to sort an array containing inner arrays based on one of it's inner array's values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$animals = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'cat', 'order' => '2'),
    '1' => array('name' => 'dog', 'order' => '1'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'fish', 'order' => '3')
);
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
$animals = array(
    '1' => array('name' => 'dog', 'order' => '1'),
    '0' => array('name' => 'cat', 'order' => '2'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'fish', 'order' => '3')
);
```

As you can see I want to sort based on the `order` key. How to do this?

Comment: Joe...maybe because he wants to display results in a certain order??  Why else would you ever want to sort anything?

Comment: @joe right now when I foreach over $animals I get it in this order: cat, dog, fish. I want it in the right order based on the order key. Unfortunately I don't have control over the code when the array gets built initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
 $animals = array(
    '0' => array('name' => 'cat', 'order' => '2'),
    '1' => array('name' => 'dog', 'order' => '1'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'fish', 'order' => '3')
);

$tmp = array();
foreach($animals as $k=>$r){
    $tmp[] = $r['order'];
}
array_multisort($tmp,SORT_ASC,$animals); // SORT_DESC to reverse

echo '<pre>',print_r($animals),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [PHP's native usort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a userdefined callback reading the order fields.

If maintaining index association is critical use [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...using usort()

```
$animals = array(
'0' => array('name' => 'cat', 'order' => '2'),
'1' => array('name' => 'dog', 'order' => '1'),
'2' => array('name' => 'fish', 'order' => '3')
);


function build_sorter($key) {
   return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
       return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
   };
}

usort($animals, build_sorter('order'));

var_dump($animals);
```